# Rounding time using two cases in one formula

Tags: excel, rounding

I want a formula for Excel work like that

08:45   turns into 8:00
and at the same time if
8:55 turns into 9:00

So I mean ignore the minutes and round it to the hour except if the minute is 55 or above round it to the next hour as shown above.

Comment: You haven't even specified your programming language and environment. How could anyone help you?

Comment: sorry it is for Excel

Answer (score 0):

I think `=TIME(IF(MINUTE(A1) >= 55; HOUR(A1)+1;HOUR(A1));0;0)` is what you need.

Comment: Wait a minute I modified the ; to , and now it working perfectly you made my day and saved me a lot of time!. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: As you are quite new to StackOverflow, please read these topics for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. It will help you get a good answer here.